# angular roles localstorage security

Tags: node.js, angular, jwt, passport.js

im building a store in angular using JWT with passport and authguard, and only the administrator should enter in a privileged area, should i display the role in localstorage and make a function to compare if(user.role === 'admin') ?

if a user loggedIn edit his localstorage cookie and change the role to 'admin' can gain access and vandalize my application?

i didnt found so much info about roles in angular can u give some guide or link me a tutorial/book to learn more about it

Answer (score 1):

I encounter this problem as well. since I needed user role for almost every page, I used CryptoJS to encrypt the role and decrypt it on a auth service.

Here is a link for that library on github:
https://github.com/brix/crypto-js

Hope that helps
Good Luck